# How do I select a marker using the Maps V2 Android API?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am currently using the `ItemizedOverlay` class from the Maps V1 API, which keeps track of what marker (if any) is currently selected. Is there any similar functionality in Maps V2 to determine which marker is currently selected? Also, is there a way to programatically select a new marker?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

To determine which marker is selected, add a OnInfoWindowClickedListener to your GoogleMap:

```
//mMap is an instance of GoogleMap
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(getInfoWindowClickListener());
```

Override the onInfoWindowClicked() method inside of the OnInfoWindowClickListener:

```
public OnInfoWindowClickListener getInfoWindowClickListener()
{
    return new OnInfoWindowClickListener() 
    {       
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked a window with title..." + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };      
}
```

And keep track of the selected marker, perhaps with an instance variable.

To select a marker programmatically, you'll have to keep a list of all your markers, then get a handle on one and call showInfoWindow(), similar to this:

```
//markerList is just a list keeping track of all the markers you've added
//to the map so far, which means you'll have to add each marker to this
//list as you put it on the map
Marker marker = this.markerList.get(someObjectYoureShowingAMarkerFor.getId());

if(marker != null)
{
    marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OnMarkerClickListener.

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean  onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked a marker with title..." + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```