# How can i get information from a selected marker? (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an activity with a Google Map and some markers placed on the map. Additionaly, i have some TextViews that shows info from the first selected marker on the map.

I want to be able to access information from any selected marker from my map. I want my information from my Textviews to change when I click another marker. Can you tell me what method should I call or what should I do to be able to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html)

and to get the marker title and marker snippet check these links

- [getTitle ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getSnippet())
- [getSnippet ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getSnippet())

Add the marker as follows

```
myMarker = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("My Spot")
                    .snippet("This is my spot!"));
```

then, set the `TextView` using `getTitle()` or `getSnippet()` as follows

```
tv.setText(myMarker.getTitle());
```

or

```
tv.setText(myMarker.getSnippet());
```

**and**

to change the text of the `TextView` each time you click the marker detect the clicks with an `onClickListener()`. May be like this..

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
{   
     @Override
     public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
           if(marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
           } else {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
           }
           tv.setText(myMarker.getTitle());    //Change TextView text here like this
           return true;
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

But i want to get the info in my textviews to change when i click the marker.

I found this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312936/how-do-i-select-a-marker-using-the-maps-v2-android-api

It helped me, but i want the information to change when i select the marker, not the info window. Can i somehow do that?

Comment: Another question if i may ask please. Now that i have overrided the "onMarkerClick", the InfoWindow does not show anymore. How can I make it appear again? What should I add in the overrided method?

Comment: Worked again! Thanks alot mate, got bless nice helpful people like you!